# Brian Tracy 1000% Productivity Formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi I recently watched a Brian Tracy productivity video and I am curious about the maths behind this, I understand compound interest well but I cannot seem to get the numbers working for me.

How does Brian get the 1004%? The problem is:

> If you become one tenth of one percent more productive each day, five
>   days per week, at the end of one week you will be one half of one
>   percent more productive (1/10 x 5 = .5%). At the end of four weeks,
>   you will be two percent more productive (4 x .5% = 2%). At the end of
>   fifty-two weeks, you will be 26% more productive than you were at the
>   beginning of the year (13 x 2% =26%) or (52 weeks * 0.5% a week).
>
> By becoming 26% more productive over the course of a year, and
>   continuing to improve by one tenth of one percent per day, five days a
>   week, you will actually double your overall productivity, performance
>   and output in 2.7 years.
>
> If you continue learning, growing and becoming more effective and
>   efficient, an improvement of 26% per year, compounded over ten years,
>   will result in an increase of 1004% in your overall productivity in
>   one decade.

Comment: I couldnt find a "compound interest" tag

Comment: Do not expect perfect mathematics in statements like these. There seems to be some confusion among percent and percentages.

Comment: Are you getting close to 1004% with your calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $26\%$ a year improvement is fairly simple:  $0.1\%\times 5 \times 52$.  If it had been compound growth then it would be higher as $1.001^{5 \times 52} \approx 1.297$

The $2.7$ years for doubling looks wrong as $1.26^{2.7}\approx 1.866$ while $1.26^{3}\approx 2$.  Perhaps it came from applying the "[rule of 72](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72)" or "rule of 70" as approximations.

Compounding $26\%$ over ten years gives $1.26^{10}\approx 10.086$  which is about ten times.  This is not a $1004\%$ increase, but nearer to a $909\%$ increase.

Answer (score 1):

I think all he did was take 26% increase in one year, and compound it over 10 years.

So, 
$$
1.26^{10} = 10.09
$$
10.09 can be thought of as a 909% increase, which is *somewhere around what he said.

If you want to get slightly more detailed, you can compound it per day

$$
1.001^{5*52*10} = 13.44
$$